# Python @lru_cache() how to store key with different value

Tags: python-3.x, caching, lru

I understand that following caches an item in dict with key as `1` and value as `"this is item 1 value"`

```
@lru_cache()
def get_item(item_id):
    return {item_id: f"this is item {item_id} value"}

item = Item(id=1, name="foo")
get_item(item.id)
```

What if I want to store value as entire `item` object ?

So that later in the code, I can fetch the `item` object from cache by its id.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary?

Comment: ofcourse I can. But Just want to check if its possible with lru_cache().

Comment: If you want to store `item`, pass it as the parameter to `get_item`.

Comment: I can't. Later somewhere in the code, I will only have item ID. I want to fetch item object by Id. I'd want `item = get_item(1)` to return full Item Object.

Comment: What you want is not possible with @lru_cache. It is intended to cache function returned values. Even your initial assumption is incorrect: the cache value is `{1: "this is item 1 value"}`, not `"this is item 1 value"`.